# Error on job that retrieves data from an external FTP server

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I started in a large company as an IT consultant. One of my tasks is to manage an application that has a SQL database.

I have very limited knowledge of SSIDB and SQL Server Management Studio - but I am willing to learn.
The SQL database is updated with external data. This can be done by users directly in the application, but it also happens through a scheduled job. The job runs from SQL manager. The job has only two steps, one of which is to execute a dtsx package.

The dtsx package is set up retrieves data from an external FTP server and merges the data into the database. The job was made by my predecessor and has run flawlessly for a very long time.
Now we are in the situation where the FTP, supplying the data, has been changed.
I have therefore been inside the Connection managers and changed to the new FTP server.

Running the jobs however we still get the following error message:

> Failed to configure a connection property that has the following path: \Package.Connections[FTPConnection].Propterties[ChunkSize]. An error occurred while setting the value of property “ChunkSize”. The error returned is 0x80020009 “The ValidateDates has been migrated. The package must be saved to retain migration changes.”

I have checked the Connection managers and the ChunkSize is unchanged from when the job was working correctly. ChunkSize is set to 1000, both in the Connection manager, but also in the dtsx package itself.

When I have searched for the problem, it is mentioned that it may have something to do with the connection to the FTP server. So I have checked the connection to the FTP server from the server where the SQL database is located - and there is a connection. In addition to this, I have also made sure that there is a firewall rule that allows traffic between the two servers. This is ensured across protocols and port 20-22
When the job itself is run, however, no traffic leaves the server. So I believe the problem is with the job itself.

Edit: after having done a validation of the package i have gotten the following.

> Failed to configure a connection property that has the following path: \Package.Connections[FTPConnection].Propterties[ChunkSize]. An error occurred while setting the value of property “ChunkSize”. The error returned is 0x80020009 “The ValidateDates has been migrated. The package must be saved to retain migration changes.”.
> : at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ISServerExec.ConnectionParametersManager.ConfigureProperties(Sting parameterName, object parameterValue)
> at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ISServerExec.ConnectionParametersManager.ConfigureProperties()
> at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ISServerExec.ProjectOperator.ValidatePackageWithReference(Int64 validationId, Int64 infold, Int64 projectId, String packageName, Int64 versionId, Nullable'1 referenceId, Project isserverProject, Boolean OfflineMode)

I hope my description is comprehensive enough - otherwise please do write follow-up questions.

ps english is not my first language. sorry if something didn't turn out too well.

Comment: How did you amend the package?

Comment: The entire project is on a GIT server. From here I was able to download it and open it in Visual Studio. Here I could confirm that ChunckSize is set to 1000, as it also is in the connection manager. My understanding of the connection manager is that it overwrites the properties that are in the package itself. The actual changes to the FTP connection are made directly in connection manager in SQL Manager.

Comment: So you amended the package with Visual Studio? With what version? Did it match the original version of the package? Did it prompt to upgrade the package? Does the package SQL Server version match the production SQL Server version?

Comment: No, i did not amended the package with Visual Studio. Just used it for checking the value of the ChunkSize Propterties.

Comment: How could you not have changed the package if you *"have therefore been inside the Connection managers and changed to the new FTP server"*?

Comment: In SQL Server managerment Studio i right-click the dtsx file, press configure - And from there go into Connection managers. In here i can change the property.

Comment: The error itself is related to running wrong package versions on wrong SQL Servers (see e.g. https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/133872/5203). Have you also upgraded SQL Server recently? Or possibly this manifests only when overriding the package parameters from the dtsx utility; can you make sure the package version matches the SQL Server version?

Comment: Hi. The PackageFormatVersion is 8 and the microsoft sql server management studio version is 2017.  Could it be how the package is run?

Comment: The management studio version has little relation to the SQL Server version.

Comment: Okay. I am sorry about that. I must have misunderstood you. Our SQL Server is version 14.0.1.